# convert any file type to pdf using Java API

Tags: java, pdf, powerpoint, docx, xlsx

Can you please let me know which java api (open source - Devlopment & Commercial) can be used to convert any file type (e.g. doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx) to pdf. Those files may contain text, image, graph,chart, style etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show what are you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can user iText library for creating pdf documents, see: http://itextpdf.com/. For reading the doc, docx, xls, etc. files I suggest using apache poi library, see: http://poi.apache.org/