# Any open source api to covert to pdf file in JAVA

Tags: java

I Need to convert below file format to pdf format.
TIF,TIFF,TXT,JPG,JPEG,BMP,DOC,DOCX,XLS,XLSX,PPT,PPTX,GIF,PDF

Do we have any open source API to convert into PDF. I tried APACHE POI. but its not look sufficient. Let me know any open source api is available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert any file type to pdf using Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382186/convert-any-file-type-to-pdf-using-java-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a PDF that contains nothing but an image is quite easy using the iText library; its web site has an example that shows how to do that.

Converting Excel files is not hard; the Apache POI library can be used for reading the Excel file, and then again the iText library can be used for creating PDFs that contain tables.

Word can be dealt with in a similar manner (POI also supports it), but it'll be quite a bit tricker, especially if the file contains tables and images, since the POI API for handling DOC/DOCX isn't as advanced as the one handling XLS/XLSX, and of course Word files have a less regular structure than Excel files.

JAI won't be of any help with this.

There are commercial packages available that can be used from Java applications; you may want to investigate those before embarking on writing your own, especially if you need to deal with complex documents - writing your own converter that handles those and generates good quality output could easily take a couple of weeks (or a month) of your time.

Comment: iText is not open source. when we want to sell a software product that includes iText or use iText in any commercial webservice, than we need to buy a license.